# Android SDK. HTTP POST double variable

Tags: android, variables, web, http-post, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to send GPS data over http request.

The problem is that the GPS data is in double format and `nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(String, String)`

will not allow double values.

How do I send double values or convert the double to a string?

Thanks,

```
httpclient client = new defaulthttpclient();
httppost post = new httppost("web address");
post.setEntity(new UrlencodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpresponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to use two nameValuePairs to send latitude and longitude separately:

```
double latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
double longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",Double.toString(latitude)));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",Double.toString(longitude)));
```

Comment: I cannot use the `toString()` function because of a primative double type. Could I send double directly over a get request? The get url should be able to hold the concatenated variables directly.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you may use Double.toString(value), I'll edit the answer to reflect that.